# I need a source for three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d-model

Can somebody give me some information or a tutorial, to import an 3d model in format .obj with three.js?

Comment: Somebody surely can, but certainly not on this site. Please read the FAQ before posting. No downvote for the sake of "SO Summer of Love"

Answer (score 3):

You can get examples from here:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/examples

For importing models in .obj format,you may get the example from:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html